# Switch to next video from Youtube API (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am attempting to have the next video in a channel play right after the other. Currently, the website has the videos showing one after the other, but my goal is to show one video and the second one plays right after the other is done. I have the function set up for the video ending, but right now it just causes an alert. I am using the Youtube Data API to pull in the videos and their information.

[image: Current View of React App]

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  videos: [],
};

}

  componentDidMount() {
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='APIKey'&channelId=UCXIJgqnII2ZOINSWNOGFThA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2')
.then(results => {
  return results.json();
}).then(data => {
  let videos = data.items.map((videos) => {
    return(
      <div key={videos.items}>
      <YouTube
              className="player"
              id="video"
              videoId={videos.id.videoId}
              opts={VIDEO_OPTS}
              onEnd={this.playNextVideo}
            />
      <h2>{videos.snippet.title}</h2>
      <p className="channel">Video by: {videos.snippet.channelTitle}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  this.setState({videos: videos});
  console.log("state", this.state.videos);
})

  }

  playNextVideo = () => {
    alert('The video is done!');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do few things a little bit different.

First save the `results.json();` to your videos variable in the state and not the whole youtube component, that's bad practice.

Second save another variable in your state that indicates the current playing video id (playingVideoId). Initialize it in the componentDidMount and change it in your playNextVideo function like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.index=0;    
}        

componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key='APIKey'&channelId=UCXIJgqnII2ZOINSWNOGFThA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2').then(results => {
          this.setState({videos: results.json()});
          this.setState({playingVideoId: this.state.videos[this.index]});
        })}

playNextVideo = () => {
              this.setState({playingVideoId: this.state.videos[++this.index]});         
          }
```

Now use the render function to render the component

```
render() {
    return(
          <YouTube
                  className="player"
                  id="video"
                  videoId={this.state.playingVideoId}
                  opts={VIDEO_OPTS}
                  onEnd={this.playNextVideo}
            />
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. When I compile the website it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'playingVideoId' of null.

Comment: Hey mark i did not write the whole code. I was just trying to explain the idea with an example so don't take the code as it is. My guess check that this line this.state.videos[this.index]}) returns what you expect.